# Website deployment from Live to Local

Tags: php, deployment, configuration, frameworks

I have deployed my website from Live server to local machine with the purpose of  making some changes in local server before go to live.

I have done all the activities related to deployment like get all the files and folders through ftp and import live database into the local phpmyadmin, even i did database configuration also.

After doing all these steps My website is running properly on local server, But i got some Notice error in all the pages regarding undefined variable.
What type of activities i have to do for removing all Notices.
Even i don't know this website in which framework or on which CMS or in core php.

Could you please tell me this website (www.engageguru.com) on which php framework and what type of activities i have to do for removing all Notices Undefined variable.

Thanks

Comment: The "type of activity" you have to indulge in is called "debugging". Either that, or tune off the error_reporting level.

Comment: @Julien What type of debugging i need to do. When i apply error_reporting() then we can hide notices but can it will affect with my functionality? or code?